# How to remove <li></li> element with jQuery on Ideal forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, idealforms

I have problem to remove, hide `<li></li>` element on IdealForms, its easy to hide first and last, please see below. However how do I hide elemnt number 4, 5 and 6?

```
$('.idealsteps-nav li:first').hide();
$('.idealsteps-nav li:last').hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With CSS3 selector**

If you want your code to be consistent with what you have done with hiding the first and the last element with selector, you can do something similar:

```
$('.idealsteps-nav li:nth-child(4)').hide();
$('.idealsteps-nav li:nth-child(5)').hide();
$('.idealsteps-nav li:nth-child(6)').hide();
```

Comment: In this case, `li:nth-of-type(4)` should also produce an equivalent result. Due to the fact that there should not be other element types than `li` in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('.idealsteps-nav li:not(:first,:last),').hide();
```

Comment: what about if I would like to keep 1,2,3 and 7 just remove 4,5,6

Comment: @FenixDolores then you should go for Tao P.R. answer. I just saw your code and thought you only wanted to keep other elements than first and last

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<ul id="sortable">
   <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">First <a href='#' title='delete' class="itemDelete">x</a></li>
   <li id="2" class="ui-state-default">Second <a href='#' title='delete' class="itemDelete">x</a></li>
   <li id="3" class="ui-state-default">Third <a href='#' title='delete' class="itemDelete">x</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**JS**

```
 $('#sortable').on('click', '.itemDelete', function() {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
    });
```